# Does Microsoft Edge on iPad support push notifications?

Tags: apple-push-notifications, microsoft-edge, ipados

I did some research regarding the question if you can somehow send push notifications from a website on an iPad.

Now I'm asking myself, if this is just a Safari specific thing or a iOS/ iPadOS problem - I just can't find any specific information.

Comment: You can try the demo on [this page](https://webpushdemo.azurewebsites.net/#does-it-work) in Edge on iPad to see if push notifications can work well. And for push notifications working, you need to go to **Settings-> Cookies and site permissions-> Notifications-> Ask before sending (recommended)** to enable notifications in Edge settings [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9osp0.png).